# Gatsby Cloud - Build Failing with: WebpackError: /usr/src/app/www/public/render-page.js:4464

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-leaflet, gatsby-cloud

I've run into an issue with a build on Gatsby Cloud that's got me stumped, and for which I can't find any information online!

I have a site build that works fine locally (i.e. on my laptop), however when run on Gatsby Cloud consistently results in the following error:

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 0.302s
ERROR Building static HTML failed
   5 |   };
   6 |
>  7 |   module.exports["default"] = module.exports, module.exports.__esModule = true;
     |   ^
   8 |   return _setPrototypeOf(o, p);
  10 |
   9 | }
  - setPrototypeOf.js:7 
    [project]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/setPrototypeOf.js:7:3
  WebpackError: /usr/src/app/www/public/render-page.js:4464
  - utils.js:267 
  - utils.js:103 
    [project]/[@gatsbyjs]/reach-router/lib/utils.js:267:1
    [project]/[@gatsbyjs]/reach-router/lib/utils.js:103:1
  - utils.js:241 
    [project]/[@gatsbyjs]/reach-router/es/lib/utils.js:241:4
  - history.js:48 
    [project]/[@gatsbyjs]/reach-router/lib/utils.js:127:1
  - utils.js:127 
    [project]/[@gatsbyjs]/reach-router/es/lib/history.js:52:1
  - history.js:52 
    [project]/[@gatsbyjs]/reach-router/es/lib/history.js:48:1
  - extends.js:20 
    [project]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/extends.js:20:1
    [project]/[@gatsbyjs]/reach-router/lib/utils.js:166:1
  - utils.js:166 

not finished Caching HTML renderer compilation - 0.381s
not finished Caching JavaScript and CSS webpack compilation - 11.935s
ERROR Failed to compile: Error: Exited with code 1
```

Over 3 attempted builds, the file and line number for the webpack error is consistently the same. However as I'm not a web dev (this is a community project I'm volunteering on, where there's no professional web devs) and am really just hacking away on copy-and-paste code... I've hit a wall here and have no idea how to get past this. I'd really appreciate any help please. Especially as, being a community project with a budget of exactly zero, I'm not able to use Gatsby's commercial support here!

Thanks in advance for ay help anyone can offer

Comment: Does it build locally? Can you share your `gatsby-config.js` too? Specially the webpack configuration part.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ferran. It does build and serve completely fine locally. Here's my `Gatsby-config.js`:  [link](https://github.com/binghamchris/paddelbuch/blob/main/gatsby-config.js)

Comment: Have you set your environment variables in the cloud?

Comment: Yep, both of the environment variables are set in Gatsby Cloud with the same values and names as used to build locally. In trying (futilely ☹️) to troubleshoot this further I’ve noticed 2 things: 1. I have a different Node version locally than is used on Gatsby Cloud; 16.4.0 locally vs. 12.22.1 on the cloud; 2. the render-page.js file doesn't seem to be created when I build locally... although its's totally unclear to me why this is I'm afraid  Does this help narrow it down at all please @fbuireu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something builds locally but doesn't in any server environment (Netlify or Gatsby Cloud in this case) it's usually caused by a mismatch of versions between Node environments. In this case, you gave me the clue:

> I have a different Node version locally than is used on Gatsby Cloud;
> 16.4.0 locally vs. 12.22.1

This means that you are running different dependency version, causing different behaviors in both environments.

In Gatsby's Cloud environment, you can customize the [Node version by setting the `NODE_VERSION`](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052322954-Environment-Variables-Specific-to-Gatsby-Cloud) environment variable to `16.4.0`. That should fix your issue. Because according to the documentation, it defaults to `12`:

> `NODE_VERSION`: Specify the version of Node.js your project should use.
> For example, `NODE_VERSION=10`. Defaults to 12.

Comment: That's great thanks Ferran, it solved the problem right away! ... of course now there's an error somewhere in my Leaflet code that, naturally, only crops up in the production deployment and not in any of my local dev builds/tests ... but that's for another day. Thanks so much for your help.